# Scikit learn GridSearchCV AUC performance

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation, grid-search, auc

I'm using GridSearchCV to identify the best set of parameters for a random forest classifier.

```
PARAMS = {
    'max_depth': [8,None],
    'n_estimators': [500,1000]
}
rf = RandomForestClassifier()
clf = grid_search.GridSearchCV(estimator=rf, param_grid=PARAMS, scoring='roc_auc', cv=5, n_jobs=4)
clf.fit(data, labels)
```

where data and labels are respectively the full dataset and the corresponding labels.

Now, I compared the performance returned by the GridSearchCV (from `clf.grid_scores_`) with a "manual" AUC estimation:

```
aucs = []
for fold in range (0,n_folds):
    probabilities = []
    train_data,train_label = read_data(train_file_fold)
    test_data,test_labels = read_data(test_file_fold)
    clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 1000,max_depth=8)
    clf = clf.fit(train_data,train_labels)
    predicted_probs = clf.predict_proba(test_data)
    for value in predicted_probs:
       for k, pr in enumerate(value):
            if k == 1:
                probabilities.append(pr)
    fpr, tpr, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(test_labels, probabilities, pos_label=1)   
    fold_auc = metrics.auc(fpr, tpr)
    aucs.append(fold_auc)

performance = np.mean(aucs)
```

where I manually pre-split the data into training and test set (same 5 CV approach).

The AUC values returned by `GridSearchCV` are **always higher** than the one manually calculated (e.g. 0.62 vs. 0.70) when using the same parameter for `RandomForest`.
I know that different training and test split might give you different performance but this occurred constantly when testing 100 repetitions of the GridSearchCV. Interesting, if I use the `accuarcy` instead of `roc_auc` as scoring metric, the difference in performance is minimal and can be associated to the fact that I use different training and test set. Is this happening because the AUC value of `GridSearchCV` is estimated in a different way than by using `metrics.roc_curve`?

Comment: GridSearchCV when supplied with 'roc_auc', uses [`roc_auc_score`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html#sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score). Use that and check if still getting different scores.

Comment: I still get different scores, in fact the two methods provide exactly the same AUC values.

Comment: did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49061575/why-when-i-use-gridsearchcv-with-roc-auc-scoring-the-score-is-different-for-gri ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why when I use GridSearchCV with roc\_auc scoring, the score is different for grid\_search.score(X,y) and roc\_auc\_score(y, y\_predict)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49061575/why-when-i-use-gridsearchcv-with-roc-auc-scoring-the-score-is-different-for-gri)