# How can AUC differ from GridSearchCV AUC?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation, grid-search, auc

I am building an MLPClassifier model in sci-kit learn. I used gridSearchCV with roc_auc to score the model. Mean train and test scores are around 0.76, not bad. The output of `cv_results_` is:

```
Train set AUC:  0.553465272412
Grid best score (AUC):  0.757236688092
Grid best parameter (max. AUC):  {'hidden_layer_sizes': 10}

{   'mean_fit_time': array([63.54, 136.37, 136.32, 119.23, 121.38, 124.03]),
    'mean_score_time': array([ 0.04,  0.04,  0.04,  0.05,  0.05,  0.06]),
    'mean_test_score': array([ 0.76,  0.74,  0.75,  0.76,  0.76,  0.76]),
    'mean_train_score': array([ 0.76,  0.76,  0.76,  0.77,  0.77,  0.77]),
    'param_hidden_layer_sizes': masked_array(data = [5 (5, 5) (5, 10) 10 (10, 5) (10, 10)],
             mask = [False False False False False False],
       fill_value = ?)
,
    'params': [   {'hidden_layer_sizes': 5},
                  {'hidden_layer_sizes': (5, 5)},
                  {'hidden_layer_sizes': (5, 10)},
                  {'hidden_layer_sizes': 10},
                  {'hidden_layer_sizes': (10, 5)},
                  {'hidden_layer_sizes': (10, 10)}],
    'rank_test_score': array([   2,    6,    5,    1,    4,    3]),
    'split0_test_score': array([ 0.76,  0.75,  0.75,  0.76,  0.76,  0.76]),
    'split0_train_score': array([ 0.76,  0.75,  0.75,  0.76,  0.76,  0.76]),
    'split1_test_score': array([ 0.77,  0.76,  0.76,  0.77,  0.76,  0.76]),
    'split1_train_score': array([ 0.76,  0.75,  0.75,  0.76,  0.76,  0.76]),
    'split2_test_score': array([ 0.74,  0.72,  0.73,  0.74,  0.74,  0.75]),
    'split2_train_score': array([ 0.77,  0.77,  0.77,  0.77,  0.77,  0.77]),
    'std_fit_time': array([47.59,  1.29,  1.86,  3.43,  2.49,  9.22]),
    'std_score_time': array([ 0.01,  0.01,  0.01,  0.00,  0.00,  0.01]),
    'std_test_score': array([ 0.01,  0.01,  0.01,  0.01,  0.01,  0.01]),
    'std_train_score': array([ 0.01,  0.01,  0.01,  0.01,  0.01,  0.00])}
```

As you can see I use a KFold of 3. Interestingly the roc_auc_score of the train set computed manually is reported as 0.55, while the mean train score is reported as ~0.76. The code to generate this output is:

```
def model_mlp (X_train, y_train, verbose=True, random_state = 42):
    grid_values = {'hidden_layer_sizes': [(5), (5,5), (5, 10),
                                          (10), (10, 5), (10, 10)]}

    # MLP requires scaling of all predictors
    scaler = StandardScaler()
    X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)

    mlp = MLPClassifier(solver='adam', learning_rate_init=1e-4,
                        max_iter=200,
                        verbose=False,
                        random_state=random_state)
    # perform the grid search
    grid_auc = GridSearchCV(mlp, 
                            param_grid=grid_values,
                            scoring='roc_auc', 
                            verbose=2, n_jobs=-1)
    grid_auc.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_hat = grid_auc.predict(X_train)

    # print out the results
    if verbose:
        print('Train set AUC: ', roc_auc_score(y_train, y_hat))
        print('Grid best score (AUC): ', grid_auc.best_score_)
        print('Grid best parameter (max. AUC): ', grid_auc.best_params_)
        print('')
        pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
        pp.pprint (grid_auc.cv_results_)
        print ('MLPClassifier fitted, {:.2f} seconds used'.format (time.time () - t))

    return grid_auc.best_estimator_
```

Because of this difference I decided to 'emulate' the `GridSearchCV` routine and got the following results:

```
Shape X_train: (107119, 15)
Shape y_train: (107119,)
Shape X_val: (52761, 15)
Shape y_val: (52761,)
       layers    roc-auc
  Seq  l1  l2  train   test iters runtime
    1   5   0 0.5522 0.5488    85   20.54
    2   5   5 0.5542 0.5513    80   27.10
    3   5  10 0.5544 0.5521    83   28.56
    4  10   0 0.5532 0.5516    61   15.24
    5  10   5 0.5540 0.5518    54   19.86
    6  10  10 0.5507 0.5474    56   21.09
```

The scores are all around 0.55, consistent with the manual computation in the code above. What surprised me is the lack of variation in the results. It appears as if I am making some mistake, but I cannot find one, see the code:

```
def simple_mlp (X, y, verbose=True, random_state = 42):
    def do_mlp (X_t, X_v, y_t, y_v, n, l1, l2=None):
        if l2 is None:
            layers = (l1)
            l2 = 0
        else:
            layers = (l1, l2)

        t = time.time ()
        mlp = MLPClassifier(solver='adam', learning_rate_init=1e-4,
                            hidden_layer_sizes=layers,
                            max_iter=200,
                            verbose=False,
                            random_state=random_state)
        mlp.fit(X_t, y_t)
        y_hat_train = mlp.predict(X_t)
        y_hat_val = mlp.predict(X_v)
        if verbose:
            av = 'samples'
            acc_trn = roc_auc_score(y_train, y_hat_train, average=av)
            acc_tst = roc_auc_score(y_val, y_hat_val, average=av)
            print ("{:5d}{:4d}{:4d}{:7.4f}{:7.4f}{:9d}{:8.2f}"
                   .format(n, l1, l2, acc_trn, acc_tst,  mlp.n_iter_, time.time() - t))
        return mlp, n + 1

    X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split (X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=random_state)
    if verbose:
        print('Shape X_train:', X_train.shape)
        print('Shape y_train:', y_train.shape)
        print('Shape X_val:', X_val.shape)
        print('Shape y_val:', y_val.shape)

    # MLP requires scaling of all predictors
    scaler = StandardScaler()
    X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
    X_val = scaler.transform(X_val)

    n = 1
    layers1 = [5, 10]
    layers2 = [5, 10]
    if verbose:
        print ("       layers    roc-auc")
        print ("  Seq  l1  l2  train validation iters runtime")
    for l1 in layers1:
        mlp, n = do_mlp (X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val, n, l1)
        for l2 in layers2:
            mlp, n = do_mlp (X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val, n, l1, l2)

    return mlp
```

I use exactly the same data in both cases (159880 observations and 15 predictors). I use `cv=3` (the default) for `GridSearchCV` and use the same proportion for the validation set in my handcrafted code. 
When searching for a possible answer I found [this post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42247020/scikit-learn-gridsearchcv-auc-performance) which describes the same problem. There was no answer. Maybe someone understands what exactly is happening?

Thanks for your time.

**Edit**

I checked the code of GridSearchCV and KFold as @Mohammed Kashif suggested and indeed found an explicit remark that KFold did not shuffle the data. So I added  the following code to model_mlp before the scaler:

```
np.random.seed (random_state)
index = np.random.permutation (len(X_train))
X_train = X_train.iloc[index]
```

and into simple_mlp as a replacement of train_test_split:

```
np.random.seed (random_state)
index = np.random.permutation (len(X))
X = X.iloc[index]
y = y.iloc[index]
train_size = int (2 * len(X) / 3.0) # sample of 2 third
X_train = X[:train_size]
X_val = X[train_size:]
y_train = y[:train_size]
y_val = y[train_size:]
```

Which resulted in the following output:

```
Train set AUC:  0.5
Grid best score (AUC):  0.501410198106
Grid best parameter (max. AUC):  {'hidden_layer_sizes': (5, 10)}

{   'mean_fit_time': array([28.62, 46.00, 54.44, 46.74, 55.25, 53.33]),
    'mean_score_time': array([ 0.04,  0.05,  0.05,  0.05,  0.05,  0.06]),
    'mean_test_score': array([ 0.50,  0.50,  0.50,  0.50,  0.50,  0.50]),
    'mean_train_score': array([ 0.50,  0.51,  0.51,  0.51,  0.50,  0.51]),
    'param_hidden_layer_sizes': masked_array(data = [5 (5, 5) (5, 10) 10 (10, 5) (10, 10)],
             mask = [False False False False False False],
       fill_value = ?)
,
    'params': [   {'hidden_layer_sizes': 5},
                  {'hidden_layer_sizes': (5, 5)},
                  {'hidden_layer_sizes': (5, 10)},
                  {'hidden_layer_sizes': 10},
                  {'hidden_layer_sizes': (10, 5)},
                  {'hidden_layer_sizes': (10, 10)}],
    'rank_test_score': array([   6,    2,    1,    4,    5,    3]),
    'split0_test_score': array([ 0.50,  0.50,  0.51,  0.50,  0.50,  0.50]),
    'split0_train_score': array([ 0.50,  0.51,  0.50,  0.51,  0.50,  0.51]),
    'split1_test_score': array([ 0.50,  0.50,  0.50,  0.50,  0.49,  0.50]),
    'split1_train_score': array([ 0.50,  0.50,  0.51,  0.50,  0.51,  0.51]),
    'split2_test_score': array([ 0.49,  0.50,  0.49,  0.50,  0.50,  0.50]),
    'split2_train_score': array([ 0.51,  0.51,  0.51,  0.51,  0.50,  0.51]),
    'std_fit_time': array([19.74, 19.33,  0.55,  0.64,  2.36,  0.65]),
    'std_score_time': array([ 0.01,  0.01,  0.00,  0.01,  0.00,  0.01]),
    'std_test_score': array([ 0.01,  0.00,  0.01,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00]),
    'std_train_score': array([ 0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00])}
```

which appears to confirm Mohammeds remarks. I must say I was quite sceptical at first as I could not imagine such a strong impact of randomization on such big a dataset that does not really looks like ordered.

I have some doubts however. In the original setup GridSearchCV came out consistently too high by about 0.20, now it is consistently too low by about 0.05. This is an improvement as the deviation of both methods has decreased by a factor 4. Is there an explanation of the last finding or is a deviation between both methods by about 0.05 simply a fact of noise? I decided to mark this as the correct answer, but I hope somebody can shed some light upon my little doubt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference in score is mainly due to the different ways of splitting the datasets by `GridSearchCV` and your function that emulates it. Think of it this way . Suppose you have 9 data points in your dataset. Now in GridSearchCV with 3 folds suppose the distribution is like this :

```
train_cv_fold1_indices : 1 2 3 4 5 6 
test_cv_fold1_indices  : 7 8 9


train_cv_fold2_indices : 1 2 3 7 8 9 
test_cv_fold2_indices  : 4 5 6


train_cv_fold3_indices : 4 5 6 7 8 9 
test_cv_fold3_indices  : 1 2 3
```

However your function that emulates the GridSearchCV might be splitting the data in a different way, say for example :

```
train_indices : 1 3 5 7 8 9
test_indices  : 2 4 6
```

Now as you can see, this a different split on the dataset and hence the classifier trained on it might behave quite differently. (It might even behave the same, it all depends on the data points and various other factors like how relevant the are, do they help to check the variation among data points, etc.).

So, in order to perfectly emulate GridSearchCV, you would need to perform the splits in the same way.

Check the [GridSearchCV Source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/f3320a6f/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py#L592) and you will find out that at line no 592, that inorder to perform CV, they call another function from `check_cv` specified [at this link](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/f3320a6f1ab2d060fd49c94a6e3386291a684ec7/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py#L1903). It actually calls either [Kfold CV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html) or [startified CV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html).

So based on your experiments I would suggest explicitly perform CV on your dataset using a fixed random seed and the functions mentioned above( either [Kfold CV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html) or [startified CV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html)). Then use the same CV object in your emulating function to get a more comparable analysis. Then you might get more relatable values.

Comment: Thanks @mohammed kashif,I will look at the code you mentioned and report back.