# Why when I use GridSearchCV with roc_auc scoring, the score is different for grid_search.score(X,y) and roc_auc_score(y, y_predict)?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation, auc

I am using stratified 10-fold cross validation to find model that predicts y (binary outcome) from X (X has 34 labels) with the highest auc. I set the GridSearchCV:

```
log_reg = LogisticRegression()
parameter_grid = {'penalty' : ["l1", "l2"],'C': np.arange(0.1, 3, 0.1),}
cross_validation = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10,shuffle=True,random_state=100)
grid_search = GridSearchCV(log_reg, param_grid = parameter_grid,scoring='roc_auc',
                          cv = cross_validation)
```

And then do the cross-validation:

```
grid_search.fit(X, y)
y_pr=grid_search.predict(X)
```

I do not understand the following:
why `grid_search.score(X,y)` and `roc_auc_score(y, y_pr)` give different results (the former is 0.74 and the latter is 0.63)? Why do not these commands do the same thing in my case?

Comment: excellent question ! putting a message to be alerted when the answer comes ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is due to different initialization of roc_auc when used in GridSearchCV.

Look at the [source code here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/metrics/scorer.py#L506)

```
roc_auc_scorer = make_scorer(roc_auc_score, greater_is_better=True,
                             needs_threshold=True)
```

Observe the third parameter `needs_threshold`. When true, it will require the continous values for `y_pred` such as probabilities or confidence scores which in gridsearch will be calculated from `log_reg.decision_function()`.

When you explicitly call `roc_auc_score` with `y_pr`, you are using `.predict()` which will output the resultant predicted class labels of the data and not probabilities. That should account for the difference.

Try :

```
y_pr=grid_search.decision_function(X)
roc_auc_score(y, y_pr)
```

If still not same results, please update the question with complete code and some sample data.

Comment: Thank you very much! Absolutely amazing, the result is the same now!

Comment: So which is "correct"?

Comment: @jtlz2 Using probabilities. As ROC is calculating the TPR and FPR.