# Why does sklearn's permutation_test_score return a different ROC AUC score than when I calculate manually using predict_proba and roc_auc_score?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, permutation, roc

I can't reproduce the ROC AUC score I get from permutation_test_score when I try to calculate the score manually using predict_proba and roc_auc_score. It matters because this could be the difference between sig./non-sig. results for a project.

Visual of the output:

[image: visual]

- (In yellow) Score from permutation_test_score = 0.5256
- (In green) Score from roc_auc_score using predict_proba = 0.5416
- (In red) 97.5 percentile line representing p=.05 sig. threshold

Here is the code that produced that visual, which I adapted from an sklearn example in their [permutation_test_score documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_permutation_tests_for_classification.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-permutation-tests-for-classification-py). The `grid.best_estimator_` object is a RandomForestClassifier that is the result of a randomized grid search with the same exact cross-validation you see below — I can include the code for that if helpful. Also, if it would help to have a self-contained reproducible example ripped straight from that sklearn example, I can provide that too (didn't for sake of space):

```
rskf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5)

n_permutations = 300
###### Use best estimator and run it on the Validation set. Validation set targets are permuted n times.
score_ofc, perm_scores_ofc, pvalue_ofc = permutation_test_score(
    grid.best_estimator_, 
    X_val, 
    y_val, 
    scoring="roc_auc", 
    cv=rskf, 
    n_permutations=n_permutations, 
    n_jobs=6, 
    random_state=42,
    verbose=1
)

###### manual calculation of roc_auc score
y_pred_val = grid.best_estimator_.predict_proba(X_val)[:,1]
roc_auc_val = roc_auc_score(y_val, y_pred_val)
p_val_man = (np.sum(perm_scores_ofc >= roc_auc_val) + 1.0) / (n_permutations + 1)


##### Plot permutations 
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.figure(figsize = (5,5))

ax.hist(perm_scores_ofc, bins=20, density=True)
###### Compare roc_auc_val score to score_ofc 
ax.axvline(roc_auc_val, ls="--", color="g", lw=3)
ax.axvline(score_ofc, ls="--", color="y", lw=3)
###### Include line showing the p=.05 significance level
ax.axvline(np.percentile(perm_scores_ofc, 97.5), ls="-", color="r", lw=3)
ax.set_xlabel("ROC AUC score")
_ = ax.set_ylabel("Probability")     # copy-pasted all this code from the sklearn documentation, and I'm not sure why they called this "probability"

print('''
Green = Score on original data using "manual" predict_proba method
      = {}
p-val = {}

Yellow = Score on original data using "automatic" grid.score_ method
      = {}
p-val = {}

97.5 Percentile value: {}
'''.format(roc_auc_val, p_val_man, score_ofc, pvalue_ofc, np.percentile(perm_scores_ofc, 97.5)))

plt.show()
```

I've seen one or two other related questions (ex: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49061575/why-when-i-use-gridsearchcv-with-roc-auc-scoring-the-score-is-different-for-gri)) that had something to do with the difference between a scorer using decision_function vs. predict_proba, but that shouldn't be an issue here since RandomForestClassifier has no decision_function attribute. So permutation_test_score has to be using predict_proba, right? But then why am I getting different results?

Thank you for any and all help! I've been trying to figure this out for days.

#### Edit

Including my code for the original pipeline and grid search, for completeness.

```
pca = PCA()
pipe = Pipeline(
    [
        ('scaler', MaxAbsScaler()),
        ('pca', pca),
        ('classifier', RandomForestClassifier()),
    ]
)

param_grid = [
    {
        'classifier': [RandomForestClassifier(random_state=42, n_jobs=-1)],
        'classifier__max_depth' : [i for i in range(1, 8, 2)],
        'scaler': [RobustScaler()],
        'pca__n_components': [33],
        'classifier__n_estimators' : [250],
        'classifier__criterion' : ['gini'],
        'classifier__max_features' : [0.3],
        'classifier__min_samples_split': [12],
        'classifier__min_samples_leaf': [9]
    }
]
###################################################
### USE GRID SEARCH TO FIND BEST HYPERPARAMETERS ###
# SCORING = ROC AUC

rskf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5)

grid = RandomizedSearchCV(pipe, 
                          param_grid,
                          n_iter=60,                           # Seemed like the right balance between computation time and exhaustiveness
                          random_state=42,
                          scoring='roc_auc',
                          cv=rskf,
                          refit=True,
                          return_train_score=True,
                          verbose=1,
                          n_jobs=6
                         ).fit(X_train, y_train)               # Fit all iterations on training data
```

Answer (score 0):

The `score` output of `permutation_test_score` is obtained by (re)fitting the estimator ([source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/baf0ea25d6dd034403370fea552b21a6776bef18/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py#L1305)), so if you haven't set a random state in the random forest, this may differ from the model inside `grid.best_estimator_`.

Comment: I believe I did set a random state in the RandomForestClassifier. I just added my code for the original pipeline and grid search, so you can see if I added it correctly. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the added context. The problem is the datasets: the manual approach is fitted on `X_train` and scored on `X_val`, but the output of the function applies kfold cross-validation on just `X_val`.

Comment: Okay I'm not sure I understand. I tried running the grid search again but this time fitting on X_val, y_val to make it the same as the permutation test. But I still get different results for score_ofc and roc_auc_val. How exactly would I reproduce score_ofc? Thx!